# Retrieve or reset the password for PostgreSQL on Linux

Tags: postgresql, linux, password

I have installed Postgres on my Linux system. I forgot the admin password I want to reset the password. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want to reset your password you need to go to the [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file. You can do this by giving in the following command into Linux.

```
sudo subl /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf
```

2. After gaining access to the file you must change all local locations from Method md5 to trust so you can enter Postgresql without permission or without being asked for a password.
   Then place the following command into Linux:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

3. Subsequently, run the succeeding command to get into PostgreSQL:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

4. And last but not least run the common SQL Command to reset the password for User:

```
ALTER USER postgres with PASSWORD 'anewremembrablepassword';
```

Of course, you could also use another user than postgres if you considerably created one. Make sure you go back to the pg_hba.conf file to change the methods back to md5 so you always give in a password as for better security or leave it and never give in a password.

I hope I could be helpful in solving this matter.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be more generic in your answer. For one, few distributions use System V init scripts these days.

Comment: For step 1, I found my pg_hba.conf in `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf`

For step 2, `sudo systemctl restart postgresql.service`